# job.setOutputKeyClass and setOutputValueClass in Driver is mismatching with the reducer's context.write method,still program is running fine.how?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

#### Driver code:

```
public class WcDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "WcDriver");
        job.setJarByClass(WcDriver.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setMapperClass(WcMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WcReducer.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

#### Reducer code

```
public class WcReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text,String>
{   
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String key1 = null;
        int total = 0;
        for (LongWritable value : values) {
            total += value.get();
            key1= key.toString();
        }
        context.write(new Text(key1), "ABC");
    }
}
```

Here, in driver class I have set `job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class)` and `job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class)`, but in reducer class I am writing a string `context.write(new Text(key1), "ABC");`. I think there should be an error while running the program because output types are not matching, and also reducer's key should implement `WritableComparable` and value should implement `Writable` interface. Strangely, this program is running good. I do not understand why there is not an exception.

Comment: no man, just check out my answer

Comment: and this is happening because you are not providing outputkeyclass for reducer, it is for mapperclass, reducer gets ur mapper's output stored in temp memory...

Answer (score 3):

try to do this :

```
 //  job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class); 
// comment this line, and you'll sure get exception of casting.
```

This is because, TextOutputFormat assumes LongWritable as key, and Text as value, if you'll not define the outPutFormat class, it will expect to get default behaviour of writable, which is  by default, but if u'll mention it, it would implicitly cast it to the given type.;

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for your concern. I tried this,But this is also working fine and not giving any error.I think it should not matter whether we define it or not because by default it will take TextOutputformat only. Can you please elaborate your answer more.

Comment: it was giving exception on my system

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
//job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class); if you comment this line you get an error
this will for only define the key value pair by defaul it depent on the output format and
it will be text so this is not giving any error
```

Comment: Yes, After doing this, program is giving an exception. But I am not clear with the reason. Can you please elaborate it more.